# How can I compare KeyValuePair.Value with my specified value?

Tags: c#

In my task I need to add "if" statement into the `foreach` cycle and compare my value with value in a dictionary.

When I wrote `if` like this, my code has shown me message for all my strings. But I need to compare my "currentGold" with cost of armor, weapon and MagicSkill.

I don't understand how I need to specify this.

```
int currentGold = 100;

Dictionary<string, int> itemInventory = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"Armor", 18},
    {"Weapon", 19},
    {"Magic Skill", 22}
};

Debug.LogFormat("You inventory has: {0} items", itemInventory.Count);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in itemInventory)
{
    if (kvp.Value < currentGold)
        Debug.Log("You can afford this");

    Debug.LogFormat("Item: {0} - {1}g", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: _"my code has shown me messege for for all my strings"_ - yes, because every item is cheaper than the `currentGold`.

Comment: Seems all ok to me. What is the question? Or what was your expectation different from what you got?

Comment: Please specify your expectations and desired output.

Comment: FYI the first Debug.Log will only print for every item you can afford, but the next one isn't part of the `if` so will always get printed, perhaps that is your issue? This is why I always advocate using `{` and `}` for `if` blocks.

Comment: Soory for that , i didn't clearly explain what i need. I need what "if" operator compare every string with my currentGold and write what i can afford and what i can't afford.

Comment: `+`, '*', `==`, `&&` are operators. `if` is a keyword that is a part of an if-statement.

Comment: a.) you can afford everything thats lower or equal to currentGold not only lower. b.) And if has also an else branch where you can put the output for "not affordable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an else part to your [if-statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements) and you should use the `<=` operator for the comparison, as you can afford something when its cost is less or equal to your current gold reserve.

```cs
if (kvp.Value <= currentGold) {
    Debug.Log("You can afford this");
} else { // Here kvp.Value is > currentGold.
    Debug.Log("You cannot afford this");
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to select the right string:

```
Debug.Log(
    kvp.Value <= currentGold ? "You can afford this" : "You cannot afford this");
```